# Using elasticsearch_dsl to do nested(?) aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm not sure if I'm using the words correctly, but essentially I would like to do an aggregation using elasticsearch_dsl that

1. separate by date
2. separate by app
3. count unique user id

for 1, I know I have to use date_histogram, however, for 2 and 3, I'm not sure how I should form my command

for the mapping, it looks like:

```
"protperties":{
    "app": {"field1": {......},
            "name": "....",
            "id": 1
    },
    "time": {......},
    "user": {"id": 2,
             "field3": ......
    }
}
```

so both app.id and user.id are nested

My goal is to get a json object that looks like

```
{'users': {
    'app1': {date_1: 1}, 
    'app2': {date_2: 1}, 
    'app3': {date_3: 1}}}
```

where app1, app2, and app3 are app name

I've tried using `s.aggs.bucket('app.name_na', 'date_histogram', field='time', interval='day').bucket('app', app_agg).bucket('users', id_agg)` where `app_agg` and `ip_agg` are using `A` to build `{'terms': {'field': 'app.name'}, 'aggs': {'users': {'cardinality': {'field': 'user.id'}}}}` and `{'cardinality': {'field': 'user.id'}}`, or some variations of this command, but the results are either not able to form or are not what I'm looking for. I'm wondering how I can form the correct commands using elasticsearch_dsl

Answer (score 0):

For the nested aggregations you want -

> 1. separate by date
> 2. separate by app
> 3. count unique user id

I would go for:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "dates_agg": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "1d"
      },
      "aggregations":{
        "apps_agg":{
          "terms":{
            "field": "app"
          },
          "aggregations":{
            "users_agg":{
              "terms":{
                "field": "user"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:

**dates_agg** - will separate by **day**, you can define a different interval with 
[Time Units](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#time-units).

**apps_agg** - will separate by `app` using [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) - Terms aggregation also count number of doc for each bucket.

**users_agg** - will separate by `user`, the number of users with this app at that time will be the number of buckets.

Comment: so if I need to put it in elasticsearch_dsl context, I need 3 `bucket`, one after anoather?

Comment: okay that doesn't work. I got `TransportError: TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'value source config is invalid; must have either a field context or a script or marked as unwrapped')` when I tried to do `execute()`

Comment: Don't know, try [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/illegal-state-exception-value-source-config-is-invalid-must-have-either-a-field-context-or-a-script-or-marked-as-unwrapped/93222)